# Error with rendering datetime object in django templates

Tags: python, django, datetime

For a blogging app, I'm trying to get a list of all months, in which posts have been published, but find a wrong set of months rendered in the template. I hacked around and found the following results,

```
>>> date_list = Entry.objects.filter().dates('pub_date','month')
```

Above code, gives me a set of months which is correct,

```
>>> date_list[6]
 datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

The month indicates June, but when rendered with a template, the month is decreased by one i.e 'may'

```
>>> t = Template("The month is {{ month|date:'m' }}  ")
>>> c = Context({"month": date_list[6]})
>>> t.render(c)
 u'The month is 05  '
```

whereas the real value is

```
 >>> date_list[6].month
   6
```

Everything runs fine except this bug with months, Am I missing out something basic or is it a bug with django's template engine itself?

Comment: What do you get if you try this: `t = Template("The month is {{ month|date:'SHORT_DATE_FORMAT' }}  ")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your time zone? The date is in UTC, so 2012-06-01 00:00:00 in UTC time can be still a previous day in another time zone, say 2012-05-31 20:00:00 in Eastern.

Here is a link for relevant [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)